# How to re-assign value for a variable in SweertAlert 2?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I declared a variable named `check = false` and I want re-assign it **equal `true`** but when it ran through the "if" condition, it was still **equal `false`**

If you know how to fix it, please help me. Thank you very much!

```js
function deletePost(event) {
  // Get a reference to the button element
  var check = false;
  Swal.fire({
    title: "Are you sure to reject this candidate?",
    icon: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
    cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, i'am sure",
    customClass: {
      title: "my-title",
      content: "my-content",
      confirmButton: "my-confirm-button",
      cancelButton: "my-cancel-button",
    },
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      Swal.fire(
        "Rejected Successfully!",
        "The Candidate will be informed.",
        "success"
      );
      check = true;
    }
  });
  console.log(check);
  event.preventDefault();
  if (check) {
    window.location.href = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href");
    console.log(check);
  } else {

  }
}
```

I tried to re-assign the value of check equal true but I didn't work

Comment: Remove the `check` variable entirely and put the logic within your if-statement inside of your `.then()` callback instead of the `check = true;` line. The `.then()` method runs asynchronously, so the code after the `.then()` callback runs before the `.then()` runs and sets the `check` variable

Comment: You can also look into using [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to help with readability,